# How to logout user in spring security stateless (jwt token)?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, token, logout, stateless

I create a microservice system by spring,In my project I have 3 front ends and multi microservices, These front ends use (and store into cookie) jwt token to get resource from my microservices.

My user login scenario: 
When user want login from front end one I redirect to my live project (another front end) user login in my live front end and redirect to front end one and pass the token in query param, so the front end one can use this token to get resource.
When user login from front end two redirect to live, when user logged in before in cookie of live token stored and without get username and password redirect to front end two with exist token.
This is my sso :).

But I can not logout user because when user logout (delete token from cookie) how to understood other front ends the user logouted.

I think I have to create session to get status of user login.Or I need centralized token status check.

How can create this session??

My spring security code is default security of spring.

At last I apologize for my english. ;)

My live project code (UAA)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Value("${jwt.token.access-token-validity-seconds}")
private Integer accessTokenValiditySeconds;
@Value("${jwt.token.support-refresh-token}")
private Boolean supportRefreshToken;

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final ClientDetailsServiceImpl clientDetailsService;
private final AccountService userDetailsService;

public OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        ClientDetailsServiceImpl clientDetailsService, AccountService userDetailsService) {
    super();
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
      JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = 
          new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("key.jks"), "sayar1234".toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("key"));

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public-key.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);

        return converter;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(supportRefreshToken);
    defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds);
    return defaultTokenServices;
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}
}
```

other resources

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.csrf().disable() // csrf
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests() // /**
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // Actuator
            .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll() // websocket
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
    config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public-key.txt");
    String publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    return defaultTokenServices;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We are using Redis Cache/Server to store token. You can read more about Redis at https://redis.io/documentation

After Login we store user context with this token as a key and user information as value from back-end. You can also set expire time for this token.

After logout you need to delete this token and respective value from back-end.

Now every authenticated request will have this token will validate it and also check if this token exists in Redis.

Token will be missing in 2 cases

1. User has logged out.
2. Token has expired.

After every valid request we are updating the expiry time. So that token should expiry only in case of system being idle for the specific time.

This is also beneficial distributed back-end environment.